# How to limit the values to plot from an external file (Domain limiting)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to generate many plots automatically from data files. Some of them have excessing values which cannot/shouldn't be plotted. How to limit/cut the plot in a case like:

```
\draw plot[<ydomain=-1:1>???] file {Grafik/file.dat};
```

Comment: what about using `pgfplots` ?

Comment: Is it not possible without pgfplots? I mean only in Tikz?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I'm not an expert of plotting without `pgfplots`

Comment: I'm not able to do it with pgfplots. What would be the write syntax for it? I tried
`\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[domain=-1:1] file {file.dat};
 \end{axis}`

Without success.

Comment: and it's not compatible with scaling from tikz.

Comment: I add the answer with `pgfplos` so you can see the code. Don't mark it as correct because maybe there is also a way of doing this without `pgfplots`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you would want that instead of [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) but you can clip the plot with a scope style or manually.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,-1) grid[step=1cm] (5,3);
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,-0.5) rectangle (5,2.5);
\draw[red] plot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)(2,3)(3,1)(4,-2)(4.5,3)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Note that everything on top of this would bring you closer to pgfplots anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Using `pgfplots` it would be like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[restrict y to domain=0:5]
    \addplot file {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this way `pgfplots` removes the coordinates outside the domain interrupting the function:

[image]

If you don't want to interrupt the function use `ymin` and `ymax` options:

```
\begin{axis}[ymax=5,ymin=0]
    \addplot file {data.dat};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I now know how to deal with pgfplots correctly!